# Sort an array value before the foreach

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a dropdown menu that need to be sorted alphabeticaly by name.

Here's the code

```
<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php
        echo $option_value['name'];
        if ($option_value['price']) {
            ?>(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)<?php
        }
        ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I want the $option_value to be sorted by the $option_value['name']. How can I achieve this ?

**Update**

Using sort() or asort() before don't fix the problem, the order I get is

```
<option value="14598">Medium - red (0588390) [0]    </option>
<option value="14599">large - WHITE (0592167) [1]  </option>
<option value="14600">Medium - WHITE (0592168) [3]  </option>
<option value="14601">large - THE ROYALS (0592169) [0]  </option>
<option value="14602">Medium - THE ROYALS (0592170) [2] </option>
```

It sort by the value ID but I need to be sorted by it's name

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: well, [sort](http://php.net/manual/function.usort.php) it before using it?!

Comment: use usort() before the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this before your foreach:

```
function mysort($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['option_value']['name'], $b['option_value']['name']);
}

usort($option, 'mysort');
```

Comment: I get this error : Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: If this answer doesn't work, then `$option` does not look like what you presented in the question.

Comment: @Salman A: that edit is NOT correct. $option is the array that needs to be sorted!

Comment: Reverted. But look carefully :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I tested this code myself and it works as expected (making some assumptions about how $option is constructed).

Comment: @ithcy the OP is iterating over `$option['option_value']` so this is the array to be sorted, not `$option`.

Comment: You could just reverse the positions of $a and $b inside the mysort function.

Answer (score 2):

`$option['option_value']` is the array containing option values and it needs to be sorted before the `for...each`:

```
function mysort($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
usort($option['option_value'], 'mysort');
```

Then iterate just as before:

```
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
}
```

Comment: cleaner solution with a better explanation than itchy's

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

that is you can directly use 
`asort`
 function 
`asort($option['option_value'])`  or any other from options which ever you feel feasible to you.
asort will sort array based on first column entry i.e if your inner arrays first key is `name` it will help